# Why does `bash -c 'echo $0 ' ` output "bash"?

Tags: bash

```
$ bash -c 'echo $0 ' foo 
foo

$ bash -c 'echo $0 '  
bash
```

From bash manual

> ($0) Expands to the name of the shell or shell script. This is set at shell
>   initialization.
>
> If Bash is invoked with a file of commands (see Section 3.8 [Shell
>   Scripts], page 39), $0 is set to the name of that file.
>
> If Bash is started with the
>   -c option (see Section 6.1 [Invoking Bash], page 80), then $0 is set to **the first argument after the string to be executed**, if one is
>   present.
>
> **Otherwise**, it is set to the filename used to invoke Bash, as given by argument zero.

What does "otherwise" mean?

What cases does it include?

Does it include the case when bash is started with -c without any "argument after the string to be executed"?

I expected `bash -c 'echo $0 '` not to output anything, according to the second case in the quote, but it outputs `bash`.

Thanks.

Comment: "then $0 is set to the first argument after the string to be executed, **if one is present.**"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The documentation you quote gives three cases:

> If `bash` is invoked with a  file  of commands, `$0` is set to the name of that file.

(case 1)

> If `bash` is started with the `-c` option, then `$0` is set to the first argument after the string to be executed, if one is present.

(case 2; note the two "if"s, which must both be satisfied in this case)

> Otherwise, it is set to the  filename used to invoke `bash`, as given by argument zero.

(case 3).

The "otherwise" clause covers any situation which isn't covered by cases 1 and 2: `bash` isn't invoked with a file of commands, and `bash` isn't started with the `-c` option, or it's started with the `-c` option but without any argument after the string to be executed.

So yes, it includes the case where Bash is started with `-c` without any argument after the string to be executed. It also includes the basic `echo $0` case when run from an interactive shell, since the interactive shell was most likely started without either a file of commands or a `-c` option.

Comment: Thanks. What other cases does it also include?

Comment: if I run `echo $0` in a bash shell, it outputs `bash`. This case doesn't belong to the "otherwise" case under your interpretation, because it is not executed with `bash -c`. So does the "otherwise" case cover case of running a command directly in a bash shell?

Comment: @Tim I see your point, the "otherwise" case covers more than I thought; let me rework my answer a little...

Comment: `$ bash -c "echo $0" test` outputs `-bash` could you please clarify this behavior with double quotes ?

Comment: @Niloct the issue in your question is more about how double quotes work than what `$0` is set to.

Comment: Ok, the `-bash` output is due to shell expansion on double quotes and a login shell.

Comment: @Niloct that’s exactly it. The OP used single quotes because they wanted to test what happened in the subshell, so they ensured that the expansion wouldn’t happen in the current shell.

Answer (score 5):

You can have a test to understand manual better; suppose I have Bash under `/bin`.
I use absolute path to call bash with -c flag as follows:

```
/bin/bash -c 'echo $0'
```

output will be `/bin/bash` since I have used `/bin/bash` as the name to invoke Bash.
If I just use `bash -c 'echo $0'` (`/bin` is in my `$PATH`) then the output is only `bash` which is as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The bash manual doesn't describe what happens in this case, as far as I can find. What happens with `bash -c COMMAND` with no argument to assign to `$0` is that `$0` is set to the filename used to invoke bash, same as when there is neither a script nor a `-c` option.

This is standard behavior, [codified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sh.html).

For the meaning of “otherwise”, consult an English dictionary.