# Arguments in `bash -c mycommand arg1 arg2`

Tags: bash

From Bash Manual

> ```
> bash [long-opt] [-abefhkmnptuvxdBCDHP] [-o option] [-O shopt_option] -c string [argument ...]
> ```
>
> `-c` Read and execute commands from **the first non-option argument**
>   after processing the options, then exit. **Any remaining arguments** are
>   assigned to the positional parameters, starting with `$0`.

1. Is `-c` an option which takes an option argument or doesn't take any option argument? I guess it takes an option argument.

   Why does it say `-c` Read and execute commands "from **the first
   non-option argument**" instead of "from the option argument to
   `-c`"?

   For example, in the following command, is `mycommand` an option
   argument to option `-c` of `bash`, or a non-option argument to `bash`?

   ```
   bash -c mycommand
   ```
2. Does "**Any remaining arguments**" mean all the non-option arguments to
   `bash`?

   In the following command, is it correct that the non-option
   arguments `arg1` and `arg2` to `bash` are passed by `bash` to
   `mycommand` and are used as command line arguments to `mycommand`?

   ```
   bash -c mycommand arg1 arg2
   ```

   Are  the following two commands equivalent? What is the difference between them?

   ```
   bash -c mycommand arg1 arg2
   bash -c 'mycommand arg1 arg2'
   ```

Thanks.

Comment: You were asking [similar questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/292588/86440) a year ago...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why does it say `-c` Read and execute commands "from the first non-option argument" instead of "from the option argument to `-c`"?
>
> For example, in
>
> ```
> bash -c mycommand
> ```
>
> is mycommand' an option argument to option -c of bash, or a non-option argument to bash?

It is a non-option argument to `bash`, as you can see simply by adding more options in between:

```
bash -c -i 'echo 1'
```

---

> In
>
> ```
> bash -c mycommand arg1 arg2
> ```
>
> is it correct that the non-option arguments arg1 and arg2 to bash are passed by bash to mycommand and are used as command line arguments to mycommand?

No. Again, try it:

```
bash -c echo arg1 arg2
```

---

> Are the following two commands equivalent? What is the difference between them?
>
> ```
> bash -c mycommand arg1 arg2
> bash -c 'mycommand arg1 arg2'
> ```

They are not equivalent. In one, `mycommand arg1 arg2` runs. In the other, `mycommand` runs, Bash calls itself `arg1`, and `$1` is `arg2`.

---

All of these seem like questions that would have benefitted from a slight effort of experimentation.

Comment: Thanks. (1) Do you mean that `bash -c 'mycommand $0 $1' arg1 arg2` and `bash -c 'mycommand arg1 arg2'` are equivalent? (2) In `bash -c mycommand arg1 arg2`, if `$0` and `$1` don't appear inside `mycommand`, then is it correct that `arg1` and `arg2` are never used?

Comment: Michael, perhaps they would have benefitted from experimentation, but this one is a real question and a good one.  I have used Bash for a long time and never realized that `-c` **does not** accept an argument.  This is in contrast to e.g. `psql`, where the first non-option argument is taken as a *database name* (which is taken from the `PGDATABASE` variable if not specified).  So you have to put the SQL command directly after `-c` in `psql`, but not for `bash -c`.

Comment: When I run `bash -c`, it says `bash: -c: option requires an argument`, which sounds as if `-c` took an option argument